# How do I change the data type in a Glue Crawler?

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have some data from parquet files that are in my S3 bucket that we use AWS Glue to crawl to Athena. The problem is, the parquet files data types don’t match the data types we have in our SQL server database. For example, one column is “program_code” and in SQL server the data type is char” but in our parquet file it is “int64” and in Athena it is “bigint”. I want to change it from “bigint” to “char”

I tried changing the data type in the data catalog table in Glue but it would always revert back to the data type we have when I re run the glue crawler which we have to run every day. How can I change the data type permanently in Athena?